# Text Input Focussing Causes Mobile Browser to Show Content Outisde Div with Overflow Hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a single-paged web app. There is a bottom bar that pops up that comes from off-screen using overflow set to hidden.

In that popup, I have a text input. When clicked on mobile, the browser focusses on that input, scrolling so that it is at the center of the screen. Once I click done on the keyboard, the keyboard goes but the browser remains in the same position showing content that should be outisde the parent div that has overflow set to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to see exactly what you're doing to really give a good answer. Try wrapping your content in a visible container, while making the content itself "overflow: hidden"

```
#wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: visible;
}
#content {
    width: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and this previous post may help, thats where I got the snippet.
[CSS overflow-x: visible; and overflow-y: hidden; causing scrollbar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue)